# Getting error about "differs in level of indirection"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Hi I just completed coded my project, but when I trying to compile I kept getting this error. Which is `'<=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'`, i don't know what is happening, and I already check for the pointer and already put it when defining variable type and still cannot compile it safely.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
/* C Program to find Shortest Distances or Path */

#include<stdio.h>
#define WORD 200

int main(void) {
    int path, point = 1;
    int* ncity[WORD];
    char* cityname[WORD][WORD];
    float distance[WORD][WORD];
    float total[WORD];

    printf("This program will input 5 path and calculates the minimum between KL Sentral, KL & Jurong East, Singapore");
    printf("\n\t\t-------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\t\tMinimum Path between KL Sentral, KL & Jurong East, Singapore");
    printf("\n\t\t-------------------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\nPlease enter the total path that you want to calculate: ");
    scanf("%d", &path);

    for (int i = 1; i <= path; i++) {
        printf("\n\n----Path %d----", i);
        printf("\nState the number of city that the path cross: ");
        scanf("%d", ncity[i]);
        for (int x = 1; x <= path; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= ncity[i]; y++) {
                printf("\nCity %d named : ", y);
                scanf("%s", &cityname[x][y]);
                printf("\nEnter the distance to the city %d: ", y);
                scanf("%f", &distance[x][y]);
                total[x] = +distance[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    //Find the minimum path
    for (int x = 1; x <= path; x++) {
        if (total[x] < total[point]) {
            point = x;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe minimum path between KL Sentral, Kuala Lumpur & Jurong East, Singapore");
    printf("\nPath: Path %d", point);
    printf("\nTotal Distance: %f", total[point]);
    printf("\n\t\tCity Name");
    //Loop for 42
    for (int z = 1; z <= ncity[point]; z++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= path; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= ncity; y++) {
                printf("\n\t\t %s", cityname[x][y]);
                printf("\n\t\t %f km", distance[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This the error that had been listed once i started compiling my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHZn2.jpg)

Comment: `ncity[i]` is a pointer. Its type is `int *` and you are comparing it with a `int` type here - `for (int y = 1; y <= ncity[i]; y++)`.

Comment: Be careful with your loop variable ranges when they index arrays. Almost always in this case they should be starting at `0` and not `1`, and ending with `< limit` and not `<= limit`.

Comment: Aside: please get into the habit of outputting the newline *last* and not *first*.

Answer (score 0):

By using `z <= ncity[point]` inside your loop you compare 'z' to the actual number of the address where your `ncity[pointer]` value is stored. Usually it is a big 'int' value. I can't get why you need an array of pointers here, but to get the first value of the `ncity[point]` you need to derefence that: `*ncity[pointer]`. The same happening inside your third loop: `y <= ncity`. You compare 'y' variable with the number of address of your `ncity` variable. Again, pretty big number, so most likely 'y' variable will be outside of 'cityname' and 'distance' and then you will get 'segmentation fault' error. To get the whole size of 'ncity' you need to iterate though all values or just use `path` valiable inside your third loop

```
for (int y = 1; y <= path; y++) {
  printf("\n\t\t %s", cityname[x][y]);
  printf("\n\t\t %f km", distance[x][y]);
}
```